# Is there a shortcut for as_ref().unwrap()?

Tags: rust, option-type, readability

In my code I have a lot of structs with `Option<T>`s in them. I need to work with them in a lot of places, so my code is littered with struct accesses like `car.engine.as_ref().unwrap()`. This is pain for code readability.

Is there a default function on the `Option<T>` type that does the same? Like `car.engine.get()`? Of course I could write accessor functions for every struct member, but this seems like an overkill for something so basic. Am I doing it wrong?

I don't know much about macros, but is there a way to shorten it with macros?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be able to take advantage of the `?` operator that (since Rust 1.22) also works with the `Option<T>` type (like it does with `Result<T, E>`):

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar {
    foo: Option<Foo>,
    // other optional fields
}

impl Bar {
    fn use_optional_fields(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
        let foo = self.foo.as_ref()?;
        // use optional fields
        Some(foo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, that feature is [already available](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/11/22/Rust-1.22.html).

Comment: This seems to be more idiomatic than the other answer, so I'll check this. Both answers are really good.

Answer (score 10):

I can't find anything like that, which is not surprising, since `unwrap` is generally discouraged anyway. If you want to handle the error case, you can do this:

```
if let Some(ref e) = car.engine { println!("foo {}", e.serial); }
else { println!("nope"); }
```

Otherwise, you can easily write your own function thanks to extension traits:

```
trait OptionExt {
  type Value;
  fn unwrap_ref(&self) -> &Self::Value;
  fn unwrap_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Value;
}

impl <T> OptionExt for Option<T> {
  type Value = T;
  fn unwrap_ref(&self) -> &T { self.as_ref().unwrap() }
  fn unwrap_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T { self.as_mut().unwrap() }
}

// Now you can write
let e = car.engine.unwrap_ref();
```

Comment: Very valuable information. I didn't know that you can expand default types.